# Creating a new instance of an existing control? (a bit more complicated than it sounds)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0

I know that if I want to dynamically create a new instance of an existing form, I can simply do this...

```
Dim NewForm As New ExistingForm
```

... and a new instance of all of the controls from ExistingForm will be available in NewForm.

But what if I want to create a new instance of an existing *control* that's inside a separate existing form?

More specifically, let's say I have 2 forms - `FormA` and `FormB`. Inside `FormB` is an existing panel (we'll call it `ExistingPanel`). And inside `ExistingPanel` are several buttons, text boxes, etc., arranged exactly how I want them.

OK, so... inside a button's click event in `FormA`, I want to do something like this (it doesn't work, obviously, but should give you a good idea as to what I'm trying to accomplish)...

```
Dim NewExistingPanel As New FormB.ExistingPanel
```

And then I want `NewExistingPanel` to contain new instances all of the individual controls from ExistingPanel (so that I can dynamically manipulate each one individually).

So basically, my program will need to create several `NewExistingPanel`s at runtime. And I will need to access each one (and all of its child controls) individually, after they have been created.

How can I accomplish this? I've been experimenting with this for several hours with no luck so far, so figured I'd break down and ask the real professionals :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new user control, you could use a dictionary with the tag value as key and the control name as value.  Then you can access the control directly by using the IndexOfKey method.

```
    Dim NewForm2 As New Form2
    Dim ControlIndex As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For I = 0 To 2
        Dim NewPanel As New WindowsControlLibrary2.MyCustomPanel
        NewPanel.Name = "Panel-" + I.ToString
        NewPanel.Location = New Point(0 + (NewPanel.Size.Width * I), 0)
        NewPanel.Tag = "MyTagValue" + I.ToString
        ControlIndex.Add(NewPanel.Tag, NewPanel.Name)
        NewForm2.Controls.Add(NewPanel)
        NewForm2.Update()
    Next
    NewForm2.Show()
    Dim CurrentPanel As WindowsControlLibrary2.MyCustomPanel =NewForm2.Controls(NewForm2.Controls.IndexOfKey(ControlIndex("MyTagValue1")))
```

Comment: That's a great idea, tinstaafl, and seems like it may very well be my best option. Thank you very much for the detailed example! I will give that a shot.

Comment: You don’t need `IndexOfKey`; `Controls` can be indexed by name. But I would recommend just storing the panels in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a user control that lays out your sub-controls the way you want them, then create new instances of that. Add New > User Control in the solution menu, then build, and your controls should be ready to drag into the designer at the top of the Toolbox or to instantiate in code like any other control.

To expand on my comment:

```
Private somePanels As New Dictionary(Of String, YourUserControl)
```

Then you can just add them as follows:

```
Dim c As New YourUserControl()
…
Me.Controls.Add(c)
somePanels.Add("SomeTag", c) ' Instead of using Tag; if your tags are numbers, use a List instead of a Dictionary
```

And access them as:

```
Dim c = somePanels("SomeTag")
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's what I'm trying to do. I just don't know how to access the new instances (along with all of their child controls) at run-time.

Comment: @NotQuiteThereYet: Do you have the user controls created and added to your form already, or are you not quite there yet? ;)

Comment: Ha ha... I was waiting for that one :) Yes, just like I described above, FormB has a panel in it named 'ExistingPanel'. Inside ExistingPanel I have a bunch of various controls. <-- All of that was created in the designer. But at runtime, I want to create, say 12 instances of ExistingPanel. Once those are created at runtime, I need a way to get at each instance (and all of its child controls) individually. Does that make sense?

Comment: @NotQuiteThereYet: Okay, you should turn that `Panel` into a `UserControl`. This control is separate from the form for the moment. I don’t have Visual Studio right now and so can’t give you a screenshot, but I believe this is under the context menu on your solution in the Solution Explorer. Add User Control. Then you can lay it out nicely and use your user control in the form.

Comment: OK, I've added the new user control along with a bunch of controls inside it. Now when I need to dynamically access a specific instance of that user control by it's "tag" value, how do I do it? In other words, is there a way to iterate through all dynamically created user controls and find the one with a specific "tag" value?

Comment: @NotQuiteThereYet: Sure. Using LINQ, `Me.Controls.First(Function(x) x.Tag = "Whatever tag")`. But if you need to do this, you should probably consider putting them in a separate array/list/dictionary/etc. or accessing them by name…

Comment: Hey minitech, thanks for your updated reply... makes much more sense now! I really like this solution... very simple and clean. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

To add control such as panel with textboxes ang button in it ..

1. In your project - **Add > Usercontrol** --> 
   in this part you can make panel with textboxes and button as you want 
   name it as **"myPanel**" and save it as **"myPanel.vb**" --> or whatever you want
2. In your form and the button named **button1** you can add to your button1_click event :

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

           Dim mypanel1 As New MyPanel

           mypanel1.Location = New Point(0, 0)

           Controls.Add(mypanel1)
           mypanel1.TextBox1.Text = "Hi, Im new"

   End Sub
   ```

And you will get your panel at runtime ...

And you will get the textbox1.text fill with "Hi, I'm new" ...

Comment: Hey matzone... thanks, but that's not quite what I'm trying to do, because I would need to create several different instances of mypanel1, and then be able to access each specific instance (and all of its children) individually, at a later point in runtime from another subroutine. Not sure how I would be able to do that using your example. As tinstaafl suggested, I think using a dictionary may be the way to go on this one. Thanks anyways though! :)